# Как передать данные из формы на свою страницу wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

У меня есть файл, send.php, в котором осуществляется отправка данных с формы, как мне можно передавать данные на эту страницу, но при этом мне нужно чтобы на странице send.php работал плагин ACF, как это можно сделать?
Я пробовал переходить на страницу по прямой ссылке, но тогда плагин не работает, возникает ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field() in D:\OSPanel\domains\testwp\wp-content\themes\bets\send.php:122 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\testwp\wp-content\themes\bets\send.php on line 122
```

На 122 строке этот код:

```
$posts = get_field('new_post');
```

Вот полностью участок с кодом:

```
<?php 

$posts = get_field('new_post');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                ...
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо загрузить WordPress в начале вашего файла

```
require_once( 'путь/wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: А где именно находится файл wp-load?

Comment: Файл подключил, но плагин acf не срабатывает, возможно я допустил где-то ошибку?

Comment: wp-load в корне папки с WordPress. При загрузке ядра подключаются все активные плагины. Фатальной ошибки "не найдена функция get_field()" после этого быть не может.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, посмотрите пожалуйста мой новый вопрос

Comment: Формулировка "не срабатывает" - очень плохое описание ошибки. полагаю, вы имеете ввиду, что `get_filed()` ничего не выводит. Так это потому, что у вас в файле не инициализирован главный цикл WordPress, а именно оттуда берутся данные поста. Вам надо использовать второй аргумент `get_filed()` и указать id поста.

Comment: Извините, за глупый вопрос, а как узнать id поста?

Comment: Нашел id поста, это будет просто добавление $posts=get_field('160'); вместо $posts = get_field('new_post'); ?

Comment: Второй аргумент функции - это второй, а не замена первого. Откройте документацию https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: https://misha.blog/wordpress/kak-uznat-id-posta.html

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100867/discussion-between-alexander-and-kagg-design).